# How to use pubnub keys with Corona and Javascript

Tags: javascript, lua, coronasdk, pubnub

Learning pubnub as applied to Corona with a simple Web based chat app. There are two components, one is a button app in Corona that sends basic messages and receives basic messages.  The second is a simple html file with javascript to send and receive messages.  As long as I use the publish and subscribe keys called "demo" the app works fine.  As soon as I change the keys to my keys (provided by pubnub), the messages are not received.  I'm pasting in the html/javascript code first and the then the Corona second.  I don't understand how the html subscribes when it doesn't have any keys defined and not quite sure how to incorporate my keys into the html.  Hoping this is a really easy question and that someone may be willing to simply modify the javascript to enable me to use my own keys.  Here is the html first:

```
<html>
Enter Chat and press enter
<div><input id=input placeholder=you-chat-here /></div>

Chat Output
<div id=box></div>

<script src=http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub.min.js></script>
<script>(function(){
  var box = PUBNUB.$('box'), input = PUBNUB.$('input'), channel = 'z';
  PUBNUB.subscribe({
  channel : channel,
  callback : function(text) {
  var tst = JSON.stringify(text);
  var obj = eval ("(" + (''+tst).replace( /[<>]/g, '' ) + ")");
  box.innerHTML = obj['msgtext'] + '<br>' + box.innerHTML; }
  });
  PUBNUB.bind( 'keyup', input, function(e) {
  (e.keyCode || e.charCode) === 13 &&
  PUBNUB.publish({
  channel : channel,
  message : { "msgtext": input.value },
  x : (input.value='')
  })
})
})()</script>
</html>
```

And here is the corona code:

```
-- 
-- Abstract: Button Events sample app, showing different button properties and handlers.
-- (Also demonstrates the use of external libraries.)
-- 
-- Version: 1.1
-- 
-- Sample code is MIT licensed, see http://www.coronalabs.com/links/code/license
-- Copyright (C) 2010 Corona Labs Inc. All Rights Reserved.

-- This example shows you how to create buttons in various ways by using the widget library.
-- The project folder contains additional button graphics in various colors.
--
-- Supports Graphics 2.0

-- Require the widget library
require "pubnub"

local widget = require( "widget" )

local background = display.newImage("carbonfiber.jpg", true) -- flag overrides large image downscaling
background.x = display.contentWidth / 2
background.y = display.contentHeight / 2

local roundedRect = display.newRoundedRect( 10, 50, 300, 40, 8 )
roundedRect.anchorX, roundedRect.anchorY = 0.0, 0.0     -- simulate TopLeft alignment
roundedRect:setFillColor( 0/255, 0/255, 0/255, 170/255 )

local t = display.newText( "waiting for button event...", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 18 )
t.x, t.y = display.contentCenterX, 70
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Create 5 buttons, using different optional attributes
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

multiplayer = pubnub.new({
    publish_key   = "demo",
    subscribe_key = "demo",
    secret_key    = nil,
    ssl           = nil,
    origin        = "pubsub.pubnub.com"
})

multiplayer:subscribe({
    channel  = "z",
    callback = function(message)
        t.text = "I RECEIVED: " .. message.msgtext
    end,
    errorback = function()
        print("Oh no!!! Dropped 3G Conection!")
    end
})

-- These are the functions triggered by the buttons

local button1Press = function( event )
    t.text = "publish"

    multiplayer:publish({
        channel = "z",
        message = { msgtext = "sent from corona!" }
    })

end

local button1Release = function( event )
    t.text = "Button 1 released"
end


local buttonHandler = function( event )
    t.text = "id = " .. event.target.id .. ", phase = " .. event.phase
end


-- This button has individual press and release functions
-- (The label font defaults to native.systemFontBold if no font is specified)

local button1 = widget.newButton
{
    defaultFile = "buttonRed.png",
    overFile = "buttonRedOver.png",
    label = "PUBLISH",
    emboss = true,
    onPress = button1Press
}


-- These other four buttons share a single event handler function, identifying   
 themselves by "id"
-- Note that if a general "onEvent" handler is assigned, it overrides the "onPress" 
   and "onRelease" handling

-- Also, some label fonts may appear vertically offset in the Simulator, but not on 
   device, due to
-- different device font rendering. The button object has an optional "offset" 
   property for minor
-- vertical adjustment to the label position, if necessary (example: offset = -2)

local button2 = widget.newButton
{
    id = "button2",
    defaultFile = "buttonYellow.png",
    overFile = "buttonYellowOver.png",
    label = "Button 2 Label",
    labelColor = 
    { 
        default = { 51, 51, 51, 255 },
    },
    font = native.systemFont,
    fontSize = 22,
    emboss = true,
    onEvent = buttonHandler,
}

local button3 = widget.newButton
{
    id = "button3",
    defaultFile = "buttonGray.png",
    overFile = "buttonBlue.png",
    label = "Button 3 Label",
    font = native.systemFont,
    fontSize = 28,
    emboss = true,
    onEvent = buttonHandler,
}

local buttonSmall = widget.newButton
{
    id = "smallBtn",
    defaultFile = "buttonBlueSmall.png",
    overFile = "buttonBlueSmallOver.png",
    label = " I'm Small",
    fontSize = 12,
    emboss = true,
    onEvent = buttonHandler,
}

-- Of course, buttons don't always have labels
local buttonArrow = widget.newButton
{
    id = "arrow",
    defaultFile = "buttonArrow.png",
    overFile = "buttonArrowOver.png",
    onEvent = buttonHandler,
}

button1.x = 160; button1.y = 160
button2.x = 160; button2.y = 240
button3.x = 160; button3.y = 320
buttonSmall.x = 85; buttonSmall.y = 400
buttonArrow.x = 250; buttonArrow.y = 400
```

Answer (score 0):

## Combine Lua + JavaScript PubNub SDKs

You need to make sure your API keys are added in both SDK initializations.
You can easily do this in both JavaScript and Lua using the following samples.

### PubNub JavaScript

```
var PUBNUB = PUBNUB({ subscribe_key : 'demo', publish_key : 'demo' });
```

### PubNub Lua Corona

```
multiplayer = pubnub.new({ publish_key = "demo", subscribe_key = "demo" })
```

Get your API Keys at the [PubNub Customer Portal](https://admin.pubnub.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I've done as you say both in Lua Corona and Javascript (see code below), but the javascript still is not receiving data.   Below I am posting the Lua/Corona code first and the html/javascript 2nd:

Comment: I can not post the full code but this is the relevant section of the Corona Lua code.

Comment: You may be hitting a race condition of Publish vs Subscribe.  You must be subscribed on both SDKs in Lua and JavaScript **before Publishing**.  I tested your JS and Lua code successfully.

Comment: Hi and thanks.  Did you try it with a private keys vs. the "demo" key?

Comment: Yes indeed!  :-) Be sure both Lua and JS have the same keys.  Also remove all **`JSON`** lines, you don't need to do that.

Comment: Hi and thanks.  Did you try it with a private keys vs. the "demo" key? I included the code you suggested for the javascript and changed the keys to the same private keys in the Corona SDK code but can not receive.  I'll email the modified code through the Corona Support email with my keys included.  Let me know if that works with my keys.  For anyone reading this I just want you to know I beleive pubnub is one of the very most innovative products I've seen in a long time and that they really work hard to help developers, even noobs like me.  - Thanks PubNub!